# async await fatal error 3624

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a method similar to

```
public async Task<SaveResult> SaveStatus(int quotationId, int quotationStatusTypeId)
{
   using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
   {
      var offerQuotation = await RevisionManager.ReviseOffer(quotationId);
      var offerQuotationStatusModel = DataUnit.GetCurrentOfferQuotationStatus(offerQuotation.quotationId);
      scope.Complete();
   }
}

public async Task<DTO.OfferQuotation> ReviseOffer(int quotationId)
{
  //......
}
```

Sometimes this method `GetCurrentOfferQuotationStatus` throws an exception:

> ERROR An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   EXCEPTION OCCURRED:System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Warning: Fatal error 3624 occurred at Dec  6 2016  7:05PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.
>
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

The method `GetCurrentOfferQuotationStatus` looks like

```
public Model.OfferQuotationStatus GetCurrentOfferQuotationStatus(int? offerQuotationId)
{
  return Context.OfferQuotationStatuses.Include(x => x.OfferQuotationStatusType).FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive && x.OfferQuotationId == offerQuotationId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems quite clear to me:

> Warning: Fatal error 3624 occurred at Dec 6 2016 7:05PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator. A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Something serious – potentially fatal – has gone wrong on your database server. Talk to your DBA *now*. (If you are the DBA, head over to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and other places where you can get more details of the actions you should be talking.)

There is no indication that your code has a problem.

Comment: This is more a comment.

Comment: @mybirthname: prehaps but I think the implied question here is: "what is wrong with my code?" To which the answer is: "probably nothing, you have a problem elsewhere".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14554789)

Comment: @IvanStarostin: What do you think the question is here?

Comment: I think problem is not related with database.Because same method works fine without transaction scope.Any idea what can cause this fatal error?

Comment: @user1570475 A quick search indicated that 3624 is an internal assertion related to working memory corruption. There should be no expectation that every query will fail. Do the SQL Server  logs show anything?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this in hopes this may help someone else. I had a similar error, the issue was a corrupt user account in SQL Server. We deleted the account and re-added it and it resolved the issue.